# Why my Android app is opening inside Outlook application

Tags: android, outlook, applinks

I have an `Android` application that can be launched from the configured `App Link`.

My app properly got launched as a separate app by clicking a link from a browser or from other email clients like `Gmail` etc.

But with `Outlook`, when I tap on a link from the email, my app got launched within the Outlook app. See the screenshot.

[image]

On the other hand, if I just click on a `YouTube` video link from Outlook, the YouTube app got launched as a separate app.

I have following Android Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

    <provider
        android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar"
        android:resizeableActivity="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:host="xx.xxxxx.com" android:scheme="https" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".WebActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar" />
        
    <activity
        android:name="com.zos.sigcapesign.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar" />

</application>
```

After some searching I tried to change the launch mode value in manifest as follows: `android:launchMode="singleTask"`

This resolves the issue of launching my app inside Outlook and my app started launching as a separate app. But it came up with new issues.

After setting the launch mode to `singleTask`, my app only got launched first time. Now if my app is already launched and I click the link again, the app got launched with a blank white screen. In the debugger the `MainActivity` is not even hit. So nothing happens in the app and I have to revert back the launch mode to `standard`.

So, for me the issue and the question remains that why my Android app is opening inside Outlook application?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to figure out the issue and resolved it.

I have used launch mode as `signleTask`

The point that I was missing is, when the app is re-launched with `App Link`, the `onNewIntent()` function get called instead of `onCreate()`. So I have to handle the App Link case inside `onNewIntent()` function.

Now all is good. I am able to launch my app as a separate app from `Outlook`, `Browser`, `Gmail` clients etc.